# MariaDB - How to configure

Tags: mysql, fedora, mariadb, digital-ocean

I am trying to configure MariaDB on fedora 20. I have installed the packages correctly and can successfully login from the terminal using `mysql -u root -p` this gives me the following console window;

> [root@secondstory1d bin]# mysql -u root -p Enter password:  Welcome to
>   the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MariaDB
>   connection id is 17 Server version: 5.5.38-MariaDB MariaDB Server
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.
>
> MariaDB [(none)]>

So essentially on the box it is working with no issues. Now i would like to try and configure the setup to accept connections from Mysql Workbench - however I am unsure what needs configuring and where it needs configuring from.

Has anyone had any experience with this process before and if so what would i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? mysql workbench has a loading screen (when you first open it) where you add connections and give the correct parameters. have you looked at this?

Comment: Yes I have tried this but i keep getting the error failed to connect to MySQL at (ip) with user root. Can't connect to MySQL server on (ip) (61)

Comment: are you sure you are putting the information in correctly? theres quite a few settings.

Comment: pretty sure i just need to use standard tcp/ip hostname is the ipaddress i use to log in to on digital ocean, username root and password which i setup when installing mariadb?

Comment: well for my connections I have a TCP/IP port, and then the network address which is where the server is stored